# How to read an integer/double data type from a .dat file?

Tags: java, notepad, data-files, data-handling

How to read integer/double data type from a .dat file ? I used a Java program to creat a binary file and wrote an int data into it and now I am trying to open the file using Notepad/MS Word it's showing the character equivalent as ASCII value of the int number Please Help.
Eg. int I = 77
When I opened  .dat file  in notepad/MS Word it showed- C

Comment: Well, what you describe reads like you've written _binary_ data to a file but expect a _text_ editor to display the correct value. That won't work. What do you want the file to contain: the characters `77` or the binary representation of the integer which might be hex code `00 00 00 4D` (or similar, depending on byte order etc.)?

Comment: Can you show what code you used to create the file in the first place?

Comment: Thanx everyone.